# VBA Numbers only in Textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a text box in a userform to only accepting numerical input. Either user input or pasting the input. If user paste value something like this "9781292098814 paperback" or "9781292098814 online", I need those text will be remove directly before entering the excel.

I try 2 code below but one only working when user enter input using keyboards. Another one, text only will be remove once input enter the excel.

```
''remove text for ISBN column
    tmpStr = ISBNTextBox.Value

    For i = 1 To Len(tmpStr)
        Select Case Mid$(tmpStr, i, 1) '//examine current char
            Case "0" To "9" '//permitted chars
               '//ok
            Case Else
               Mid$(tmpStr, i, 1) = "!"
        End Select
    Next i
    tmpStr = Replace$(tmpStr, "!", "") '//strip invalids & return
```

Another one

```
Private Sub ISBNTextBox_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case vbKey0 To vbKey9, vbKeyBack, vbKeyClear, vbKeyDelete, _
        vbKeyLeft, vbKeyRight, vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown, vbKeyTab
            If KeyAscii = 46 Then If InStr(1, ISBNTextBox.Text, ".") Then KeyAscii = 0
        Case Else
            KeyAscii = 0
            Beep
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: The Windows Edit control does NOT prevent pasting anything. You can set it to only accept typed numbers, but not pasting. This is from the Edit Window style _`ES_NUMBER` Allows only digits to be entered into the edit control. Note that, even with this set, it is still possible to paste non-digits into the edit control. 
To change this style after the control has been created, use `SetWindowLong`._

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong, you want a textbox where only numbers can be entered (either thrugh typing or though pasting)?

Comment: Yes, if user paste input something like  "9781292098814 paperback", the word  "paperback" shall be remove automatically and left only numbers. In the textbox, I want only want to see numbers.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Let me test something before I post an answer

Comment: The concept to do it with 2 event, keypress and change, keypress other than number change to chr(0) and on change with number save to variable, but if not number rechange from variable, if this happen, prevent the event to run all event code of change

Answer (score 2):

You can re-validate the string each change.  This will work for as keyed, or pasted

This code silently removes invalid characters.  You could take other actions if you wish

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim i As Long, AsEntered As String, Validated As String
    On Error GoTo EH
    If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) Then
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        AsEntered = TextBox1.Value
        For i = 1 To Len(AsEntered)
            If Mid$(AsEntered, i, 1) Like "[0-9]" Then
                Validated = Validated & Mid$(AsEntered, i, 1)
            End If
        Next
        TextBox1 = Validated
    End If
EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = False
End Sub
```

Comment: ++ For ISBN this is sufficient :)

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: If you do not want to handle decimals then go with Chris's answer.

**Some Scenarios which will handle decimals as well**

1. TextBox has `1234`. Cursor is after `4`. User is trying to paste `sid1.2sid1.2`. textbox will have output `12341.212`
2. TextBox has `1234`. Cursor is after `3`. User is trying to paste `sid1.2sid1.2`. textbox will have output `1231.2124`
3. TextBox has `1234.56`. Cursor is after `6`. User is trying to paste `sid1.2sid1.2`. textbox will have output `1231.561212`
4. TextBox has `1234.56`. Cursor is after `5`. User is trying to paste `sid1.2sid1.2`. textbox will have output `1231.512126`

[image]

Since you have decimals involved and you want to trap pasting as well, you can try this

```
Option Explicit

Dim TextPasted As Boolean

'~~> Allow only number and decimal
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case vbKey0 To vbKey9, vbKeyBack, vbKeyClear, vbKeyDelete, _
        vbKeyLeft, vbKeyRight, vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown, vbKeyTab
            If KeyAscii = 46 Then If InStr(1, TextBox1.Text, ".") Then KeyAscii = 0
        Case Else
            KeyAscii = 0
            Beep
    End Select
End Sub

'~~> Trap the paste event (Ctrl + V, Shift Insert)
Private Sub TextBox1_BeforeDropOrPaste(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, _
ByVal Action As MSForms.fmAction, ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, _
ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, _
ByVal Shift As Integer)
    TextPasted = True '<~~ Text is pasted
    Cancel = True     '<~~ Cancel paste
    TextBox1_Change   '<~~ Call the change events
End Sub

'~~> Handle TextBox Change Events when we specifically want it
'~~> For example after pasting
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim myString As String

    If TextPasted = True Then
        On Error GoTo Whoa

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
        Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject

        DataObj.GetFromClipboard
        myString = DataObj.GetText(1) '<~~ Get the copied string from clipboard
        myString = CleanText(myString) '<~~ Clean the string

        '<~~ Output the clean string at cursor position
        TextBox1.SelText = myString
        TextPasted = False
    End If
Whoa:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

'~~> Function to extract numbers/decimal from String
Function CleanText(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex
    Dim tempString As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Global = True

        '~~> Check if the textbox already has a decimal
        If InStr(1, TextBox1.Text, ".") And TextBox1.SelLength <> Len(TextBox1.Text) Then
            .Pattern = "[^\d]+"
        Else
            .Pattern = "[^0-9.]+"
        End If

        tempString = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)

        If InStr(1, tempString, ".") Then
            Dim MyAr As Variant

            MyAr = Split(tempString, ".")

            tempString = MyAr(0) & "." & MyAr(1)

            If UBound(MyAr) > 1 Then
                For i = 2 To UBound(MyAr)
                    tempString = tempString & MyAr(i)
                Next i
            End If
        End If
    End With

    CleanText = tempString
End Function
```

Comment: After posting, I realized you also covered `RegEx` but in a slightly different way. Upvoted your answer, and I think ours differ enough for mine not to be deleted for now (unless you think differently)

Answer (score 0):

> *"I am trying to get a text box in a userform to only accepting numerical input"*

Try the following for whole numbers:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

Dim RegEx As Object: Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

RegEx.Pattern = "[^\d*]"
RegEx.Global = True
TextBox1.Value = RegEx.Replace(TextBox1.Value, "")

End Sub
```

This would remove all non-digits from a string immediately. However, if there (by accident) are multiple valid strings in a single pasted value (e.g.: `"9781292098814 paperback 9781292098814"`) this would lead to unwanted concatenation. If that would be a possibility with your users you might want to approach this differently and instead of `RegEx.Replace` we want to `.Test` and `.Execute` to return the first valid `ISBN`:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

Dim RegEx As Object: Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

RegEx.Pattern = "\d{1,13}"
RegEx.Global = True
If RegEx.Test(TextBox1.Value) = True Then
    TextBox1.Value = RegEx.Execute(TextBox1.Value)(0)
Else
    TextBox1.Value = ""
End If

End Sub
```

In the above case the `.Pattern` would be allowing digits between 1 and 13 times. Change that to whichever length you want your ISBN to go (but don't change the `1` to allow for keyboard entry).

Comment: @Amein, any luck on this particular issue?